# Using Django + easy-thumbnails/sorl-thumbnail on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, thumbnails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sorl-thumbnail

I'm having some issues using Django and easy_thumbnails on Elastic Beanstalk and I'm not really sure what's going wrong... Here's the problem:

I'm using easy_thumbnails to do my thumbnailing in the template. I like the flexibility this gives me, so I'd rather not do the thumbnailing in the model. When I upload an image it's stored in the database fine and is uploaded to and EBS volume. So far so good. My problem lies in that I can't thumbnail any images. If I turn on thumbnail debug it seems that easy_thumbnails isn't reading/finding the image. I suspect this problem may have something to do with my media url settings, but I'm at quite a loss as to what to change.

Has anyone else had experience with either sorl_thumbnail or easy_thumbnails? I'd really appreciate any guidence. On my local development server my thumbnails work perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you post the log with thumbnail debug on?

Comment: easy_thumbnails has no easy support for AmazonS3, if you switch to sorl-thumbnail it will support the save of the file that is your problem. Try to use the development version http://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

Easy-thumbnails has no easy support for AmazonS3, you can apply this setup to make it work http://gibuloto.logdown.com/posts/99941-easy-thumbnails-with-amazon-s3

As mentioned here: [Django-Storages + Easy_Thumbnails: [Errno 30] Read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257827/django-storages-easy-thumbnails-errno-30-read-only-file-system)