# Django-Storages + Easy_Thumbnails: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: python, django

I have installed easy_thumbnails and am trying to deploy my solution on to S3. I'm using https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage to separate my /media/ and /static/ folders, with media containing uploaded content.

My settings file works like this:

```
# static file config
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.DefaultStorage'
DEFAULT_S3_PATH = "media"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.StaticStorage'
STATIC_S3_PATH = "static"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'

MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_ROOT = "/%s/" % STATIC_S3_PATH
STATIC_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

But I'm encountering this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Couldn't get the thumbnail teams/alumni/images/thumbs/alumni.png: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/media'
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research I discovered http://gibuloto.com/blog/easy-thumbnails-with-amazon-s3/. This should resolve any issues one may be having in implementing easy_thumbnails using S3.